# WordPress & React Native

Tags: rest-api

I started developing a react-native android app and i thought i'd use Wordpress as my back-end since it supports Rest API.

There are several things that i'd like to ask..
I'm using: Advanced Custom Fields for post models, Disable REST Api to secure REST to logged in users, JWT plugin to authenticate users through REST & Big Boom Directory for custom post types.

Is there another way to auth users without JWT (perhaps any free auth service)? The problem is that if the user changes password, the JWT is still valid (until expiry).

Is there a way to limit authors to their own posts instead of seeing everything (in rest)? I thought about REST filtering, but that doesn't really help as it can be easily bypassed.

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#authentication-plugins

Comment: Read it already. Basic auth is a big no, JWT is what i'm trying and i dont think the official way of auth using NONCE works in react-native (or at least i didnt find anything related to it so far).

Comment: You haven’t mentioned OAuth.

Comment: I've looked into it for a bit, but i haven't found a plugin that secures REST API and is free. Any tips on that?

Comment: ? There's one at the link in my first comment.

Comment: The oauth server? That one is extremely outdated...

Comment: Yet it’s still mentioned in the official docs. OAuth is a set standard. It only needs to do one thing, so why would it need any updates?

Comment: That OAuth server is using WP Rest API (before Wordpress released the official REST Api). I've tried it, doesnt seem to work for me, while the other feature-less oauth servers do (so i'm not messing up). Either way having an oauth server inside wordpress isnt really my goal. I'll see if i can connect my wp to google to use  that for auth instead of creating my own.